# sqoop and oracle issue?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, plsql, sqoop

i am new to sqoop

can i import tables from oracle(pl/sql) to hive using sqoop,when **oracle** is installed in windows and **sqoop(v1.3.0-cdh3u5)** is installed in  **centos(5.6)** & my **jdk is 1.6**

i am familiar with mysql importing but getting error while dealing with oracle and i am struck with connection issues

due to insufficiency of  reputations i am  not able to put the code

can i achieve this with sqoop or should i use **oraoop**

so please help me,how can i do that??

Thanks in advance,
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

Described use case of moving data from relational database (Oracle in this case) to Hadoop ecosystem (Hive in this case) is the purpose of Sqoop tool, so this can be definitely achieved.

In order to support all different databases and warehouse systems, Sqoop have this notion of pluggable pieces called connectors. OraOop is example of such connector that is specialised for Oracle. As OraOop is just a pluggable piece, it can't transfer anything on it's own. You can either use Sqoop with OraOop or without. I would strongly advise you to read the OraOop [user guide](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/con/Quest+Data+Connectors) for further information how is OraOop working.

You did not attached the error that you are getting, so it's really hard to help. However If I could guess, I would say that you might be hitting very common issue when Oracle connection is case sensitive for both table and user name. Please take a look into [Sqoop Troubleshooting Guide](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_oracle_case_sensitive_catalog_query_errors) to see if this is your case.

Lastly I would recommend you to taking a look into [Apache Sqoop Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029519.do), where this and many other use cases are very deeply described.